# Change flight-attendant tag to cabin-crew

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, many of the airlines start to use **cabin crew** instead of flight attendants. As an insider, I also know that cabin crew is a wider word that includes flight attendants, pursers, cabin in charge and so.

I suggest changing [flight-attendant](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-attendant) to [cabin-crew](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cabin-crew) and make the former as a synonym to the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see from [your answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11443/why-do-flight-attendants-continue-to-stand-when-the-seatbelt-set-is-on/11484#11484) that you are a former flight attendant, so I don't doubt your ability to speak on the matter. My argument would be that Flight Attendant is still the more common term. The wikipedia page is called [Flight attendant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_attendant), the US union is called the [Association of Flight Attendants](http://www.afacwa.org/), and every time I'm on a flight, I still hear "flight attendants, prepare for takeoff."

However, I am starting to hear the term "cabin crew" in common usage, and it seems entirely possible that it may supplant FA the same way FA supplanted stewardess sometime in the future. Or we might find that cabin crew becomes a term when speaking collectively, and FA is still used as a generic term for an individual in that position - the same way we have "flight crew" and captain and FO, but we still have the generic term pilot. I really have no idea.

My point is simply that the primary tag should probably reflect the most common name currently in use, and I believe that is flight attendant. Everyone knows what a flight attendant is; some people might be confused about the term cabin crew today. Granted, there is a grand total of three questions with the [flight-attendant](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-attendant) tag, so it's not exactly a high volume tag and whether we change it or not will affect the site very little.

As far as making them synonyms, I don't think anyone would object to that.

Comment: All what you said is true, think of it this way: Professionals will most likely look for cabin crew, others will look for FA, so as lone as one if them is a synonym to the other then everyone will be happy 

Comment: I have created [tag:cabin-crew] as a synonym for [tag:flight-attendant]. If the former becomes more commonly used than the latter, we'll simply swap which one is the primary.

Comment: flight attendant is also the term used in FAA regulations....

Comment: `I still hear "flight attendants, prepare for takeoff."` here (EU, several airlines), I hear "cabin crew", I do not recall ever hearing "flight attendants"

Comment: Doesn't making one a synonym of the other leave both available for use? In which case, what, really, does it matter?

Comment: They are not synonyms, one is a subset of the other. This is not the same as the switch from stewardess and steward to flight attendant.(Funny enough I still hear the term ship's steward, but in reference to a single position on a maritime vessel, rather like a manager of the dept in charge of items like food and guest accommodation) Cabin-crew is used in context of crew resource management and emergency training, as opposed to the cockpit crew. The two parts  work together but with very different areas of focus, cockpit keeps it from crashing while cabin keeps it from becoming a flaming mob.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google ngrams, flight attendant is much more used than cabin crew.

[image]